# c# .net WCF Eventhandler completion

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, eventhandler

How do I determine when a Eventhandler for a WCF is complete?

I have two static variables that don't get set until the loop I am using to check the status is complete.

1. Create the variables and call the WCF using the Asynch functions created

   ```
   static var globalResults;
   static bool myEventComplete;
   main()
   {
       globalResults = null;
       myEventComplete = false;

       WCFClient wcf = new WCFClient();

       //create event handler for the WCF asynch call                
       wcf.MyFuncCompleted += new EventHandler<MyFuncCompletedEventArgs>wcf_MyFuncCompleted);
       wcf.MyFuncAsync(wcfParameter.ToString());

       int counter = 1;

       //Need to determine when the event handler is complete to then use the data returned from the WCF
       while (myEventComplete == false && globalResults == null && counter < 10000)
       {
            counter++;
       }
   }
   ```

//Eventhandler

```
public static void wcf_MyFuncCompleted(object sender, MyFuncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
            globalResults = e.Result;
            myEventComplete = true;
}
```

The eventhandler eventually updates the variables after the loop has completed.

If I duplicate the loop into two sections - the variables get updated in between the two loops - it seems that the event handler isn't running until after the loop (which I don't think is the case) - I just don't know how to get the update values from within the loop.

Comment: Look at [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx), or better yet, just use the [Task-Asynchronous-Pattern](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wcf/983/wcf-task-based-async-pattern-dotnet-45) instead of an event.  Then you can just do `var funcPromise = wcf.MyFuncAsync(foo); /* other stuff */; funcPromise.Result;`

Answer (score 1):

What's probably happening is that loop is running almost instantly (counting to 10,000 takes practically no time at all). And I'd actually expect the compiler to optimize away the loop unless you use the counter further down.

If the goal is to just do something when the event fires - just call the method you want to run when it completes from within the event itself. There isn't any need for the loop. Are you just attempting to "block" the code until the event fires/completes? I probably wouldn't since it's not needed - just continue the rest of your code that is called by the event itself.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Paul Mrozowski.

However, if you have to block the thread, you can block it by defining a static [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) object, and in your `main` call [WaitOne()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to block the thread and unblock it with [Set()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set(v=vs.110).aspx)

**I do not recommend this if you don't badly need it. You usually can call whatever you want in your `wcf_MyFuncCompleted`**

your main will probably look like this:

```
 // You may reduce its accessibility if needed 
public static AutoResetEvent SignalMyThread=new AutoResetEvent(false);

main()
{ 
    WCFClient wcf = new WCFClient();

    //create event handler for the WCF asynch call                
    wcf.MyFuncCompleted += new EventHandler<MyFuncCompletedEventArgs>wcf_MyFuncCompleted);
    wcf.MyFuncAsync(wcfParameter.ToString());

    // wait for one minute at most, you can specify no time to make it wait indefinitely
    SignalMyThread.WaitOne(60000); 

}
```

And just call set in your event handler:

```
public static void wcf_MyFuncCompleted(object sender, MyFuncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    SignalMyThread.Set();
}
```